# The view App.views.login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user != None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect('404')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

Its not redirecting me 404.html page or home.html page for that matter this the error i am getting I using "auth_user" database also my urls are configured properly

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view App.views.login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here the url.py file also

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("", home, name="home"),
    path("about", about, name="about"),
    path("header", header, name="header"),
    path("contact_us", contact_us, name="contact_us"),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login_view'),
    path("404/", RedirectView.as_view(url='/404.html'), name='404'),
]
```

Also I want to redirect to 404.html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a POST request, and the form is invalid, the function does not return anything. You should rerender the template with the invalid form in that case:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
            )
            if user != None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    # unindent 🖟
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: I changed the code to this then i got this error ` local variable 'context' referenced before assignment` then i removed the indent on context no errors now but its not redirecting anywhere do u want the urls.py file ?

Comment: @DhrumilShah: well the form should show the error, so the field(s) that are not valid. If you render it as `{{ form }}`, it will normally render the form with the errors.

Comment: Yess that all good but i am not able to redirect to home with authenticated user also

Comment: @DhrumilShah: so what happens in that case?

Comment: it Just displays the login page again also when i check the cookies in that i can see the post having email id an password stored also i m using auth_login database so yeah it doesn't work like i gave the right email and password it came to login page and i gave it wrong it came to login page ( i also changed redirect login to 404  the html page i created myself ) nothing works redirects to login only

Comment: but is it a redirect or a rerender, how do you render the form?

Comment: return render(request, "404.html")

Comment: It works now thank you